# Parse hex string to image/color

Tags: string, go, colors, hex

How can I parse RGB color in [web color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors) format (3 or 6 hex digits) to `Color` from `image/color`? Does go have any built-in parser for that?
I want to be able to parse both `#XXXXXX` and `#XXX` colors formats.
`color` docs says nothing about it: https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/
but this task is very common, so I believe that go has some functions for that (which I just didn't find).

---

Update: I created small Go library based on [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54200713/1723695) answer: [github.com/g4s8/hexcolor](https://github.com/g4s8/hexcolor)

Comment: Sorry, there is no such function in the stdlib. You'll have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Foreword:** I released this utility (the 2. Fast solution) in [`github.com/icza/gox`](https://github.com/icza/gox), see [`colorx.ParseHexColor()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/icza/gox/imagex/colorx#ParseHexColor).

---

### 1. Elegant solution

Here's another solution using [`fmt.Sscanf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sscanf). It certainly not the fastest solution, but it is elegant. It scans right into the fields of a [`color.RGBA`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#RGBA) struct:

```
func ParseHexColor(s string) (c color.RGBA, err error) {
    c.A = 0xff
    switch len(s) {
    case 7:
        _, err = fmt.Sscanf(s, "#%02x%02x%02x", &c.R, &c.G, &c.B)
    case 4:
        _, err = fmt.Sscanf(s, "#%1x%1x%1x", &c.R, &c.G, &c.B)
        // Double the hex digits:
        c.R *= 17
        c.G *= 17
        c.B *= 17
    default:
        err = fmt.Errorf("invalid length, must be 7 or 4")

    }
    return
}
```

Testing it:

```
hexCols := []string{
    "#112233",
    "#123",
    "#000233",
    "#023",
    "invalid",
    "#abcd",
    "#-12",
}
for _, hc := range hexCols {
    c, err := ParseHexColor(hc)
    fmt.Printf("%-7s = %3v, %v\n", hc, c, err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MHMePGcExHl)):

```
#112233 = { 17  34  51 255}, <nil>
#123    = { 17  34  51 255}, <nil>
#000233 = {  0   2  51 255}, <nil>
#023    = {  0  34  51 255}, <nil>
invalid = {  0   0   0 255}, input does not match format
#abcd   = {  0   0   0 255}, invalid length, must be 7 or 4
#-12    = {  0   0   0 255}, expected integer
```

### 2. Fast solution

If performance does matter, `fmt.Sscanf()` is a really bad choice. It requires a format string which the implementation has to parse, and according to it parse the input, and use reflection to store the result to the pointed values.

Since the task is basically just "parsing" a hexadecimal value, we can do better than this. We don't even have to call into a general hex parsing library (such as [`encoding/hex`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/)), we can do that on our own. We don't even have to treat the input as a `string`, or even as a series of `rune`s, we may lower to the level of treating it as a series of bytes. Yes, Go stores `string` values as UTF-8 byte sequences in memory, but if the input is a valid color string, all its bytes must be in the range of `0..127` which map to bytes 1-to-1. If that would not be the case, the input would already be invalid, which we will detect, but what color we return in that case should not matter (does not matter).

Now let's see a fast implementation:

```
var errInvalidFormat = errors.New("invalid format")

func ParseHexColorFast(s string) (c color.RGBA, err error) {
    c.A = 0xff

    if s[0] != '#' {
        return c, errInvalidFormat
    }

    hexToByte := func(b byte) byte {
        switch {
        case b >= '0' && b <= '9':
            return b - '0'
        case b >= 'a' && b <= 'f':
            return b - 'a' + 10
        case b >= 'A' && b <= 'F':
            return b - 'A' + 10
        }
        err = errInvalidFormat
        return 0
    }

    switch len(s) {
    case 7:
        c.R = hexToByte(s[1])<<4 + hexToByte(s[2])
        c.G = hexToByte(s[3])<<4 + hexToByte(s[4])
        c.B = hexToByte(s[5])<<4 + hexToByte(s[6])
    case 4:
        c.R = hexToByte(s[1]) * 17
        c.G = hexToByte(s[2]) * 17
        c.B = hexToByte(s[3]) * 17
    default:
        err = errInvalidFormat
    }
    return
}
```

Testing it with the same inputs as in the first example, the output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Z79xoFATpt8)):

```
#112233 = { 17  34  51 255}, <nil>
#123    = { 17  34  51 255}, <nil>
#000233 = {  0   2  51 255}, <nil>
#023    = {  0  34  51 255}, <nil>
invalid = {  0   0   0 255}, invalid format
#abcd   = {  0   0   0 255}, invalid format
#-12    = {  0  17  34 255}, invalid format
```

### 3. Benchmarks

Let's benchmark these 2 solutions. The benchmarking code will include calling them with long and short formats. Error case is excluded.

```
func BenchmarkParseHexColor(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ParseHexColor("#112233")
        ParseHexColor("#123")
    }
}

func BenchmarkParseHexColorFast(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ParseHexColorFast("#112233")
        ParseHexColorFast("#123")
    }
}
```

And here are the benchmark results:

```
go test -bench . -benchmem

BenchmarkParseHexColor-4         500000     2557 ns/op      144 B/op    9 allocs/op
BenchmarkParseHexColorFast-4   100000000      10.3 ns/op      0 B/op    0 allocs/op
```

As we can see, the "fast" solution is roughly **250 times** faster and uses no allocation (unlike the "elegant" solution).

Comment: thanks. and even the `ParseHexColorFast` gives correct colour when working with 16bit colour pallets

Answer (score 6):

An RGBA color is just 4 bytes, one each for the red, green, blue, and alpha channels. For three or six hex digits the alpha byte is usually implied to be 0xFF (`AABBCC` is considered the same as `AABBCCFF`, as is `ABC`).

So parsing the color string is as simple as normalizing it, such that it is of the form "RRGGBBAA" (4 hex encoded bytes), and then decoding it:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "image/color"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    colorStr := "102030FF"

    colorStr, err := normalize(colorStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    b, err := hex.DecodeString(colorStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    color := color.RGBA{b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3]}

    fmt.Println(color) // Output: {16 32 48 255}
}

func normalize(colorStr string) (string, error) {
    // left as an exercise for the reader
    return colorStr, nil
}
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/aCX-vyfMG4G

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any 2 hex digits into an integer using [`strconv.ParseUint`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseUint)

```
strconv.ParseUint(str, 16, 8)
```

The `16` indicates base 16 (hex) and the 8 indicates the bit count, in this case, one byte.

You can use this to parse each 2 characters into their components

https://play.golang.org/p/B56B8_NvnVR

```
func ParseHexColor(v string) (out color.RGBA, err error) {
    if len(v) != 7 {
        return out, errors.New("hex color must be 7 characters")
    }
    if v[0] != '#' {
        return out, errors.New("hex color must start with '#'")
    }
    var red, redError = strconv.ParseUint(v[1:3], 16, 8)
    if redError != nil {
        return out, errors.New("red component invalid")
    }
    out.R = uint8(red)
    var green, greenError = strconv.ParseUint(v[3:5], 16, 8)
    if greenError != nil {
        return out, errors.New("green component invalid")
    }
    out.G = uint8(green)
    var blue, blueError = strconv.ParseUint(v[5:7], 16, 8)
    if blueError != nil {
        return out, errors.New("blue component invalid")
    }
    out.B = uint8(blue)
    return
}
```

Edit: Thanks to [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603316) for the correction

Comment: To parse a uint8, use `ParseUint`, not `ParseInt`, and set the last argument to 8. Otherwise things like `"#-e-4-c"` are considered valid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of what you are doing, you can give this as a direct argument to the functions.

```
// HexColor converts hex color to color.RGBA with "#FFFFFF" format
func HexColor(hex string) color.RGBA {
    values, _ := strconv.ParseUint(string(hex[1:]), 16, 32)
    return color.RGBA{R: uint8(values >> 16), G: uint8((values >> 8) & 0xFF), B: uint8(values & 0xFF), A: 255}
}
```

test

```
fmt.Println(HexColor("#5a9337")) // -> {90 147 55 255}
```